# Android: sending parameters between two activities failed

Tags: android, android-intent, parameters, android-activity

I'm doing a simple Android application (a measure converter) and I'm using two activities: the first activity is the main application and the second activity it's for display the result.

When I put the value, select the type of conversion (yards to centimetres, for example) and click on the result button, the result only appears in the first activity (not the second activity).

This is my code:

ActivityMain.java

```
package displayinsecact.project;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class ActivityMain extends Activity{

private EditText etxt;
private TextView txtViewRes;
private CheckBox chkBoxYarCen, chkBoxCenYar, chkBoxYarMet, chkBoxMetYar,     chkBoxYarPie, chkBoxPieYar;

private ConversorMedidas current;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initialUISetup();

    txtViewRes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewRes);

}

public void initialUISetup(){
    etxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxt);
    txtViewRes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewRes);
    chkBoxYarCen=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBoxYarCen);
    chkBoxCenYar=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBoxCenYar);
    chkBoxYarMet=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBoxYarMet);
    chkBoxMetYar=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBoxMetYar);
    chkBoxYarPie=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBoxYarPie);
    chkBoxPieYar=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBoxPieYar);
}

public void exchange(View v){
    double aux=0;

    if(chkBoxYarCen.isChecked()==true){
        current=new convYarCen();
            aux=current.yardasCentimetros(Double.parseDouble(etxt.getText().toString()));
    }
    if(chkBoxCenYar.isChecked()==true){
        current=new convYarCen();
        aux=current.yardasMetros(Double.parseDouble(etxt.getText().toString()));
    }
    if(chkBoxYarMet.isChecked()==true){
        current=new convYarMet();
        aux=current.yardasMetros(Double.parseDouble(etxt.getText().toString()));
    }
    if(chkBoxMetYar.isChecked()==true){
        current=new convYarMet();
            aux=current.yardasCentimetros(Double.parseDouble(etxt.getText().toString()));
    }
    if(chkBoxYarPie.isChecked()==true){
        current=new convYarPie();
            aux=current.yardasCentimetros(Double.parseDouble(etxt.getText().toString()));
    }
    if(chkBoxPieYar.isChecked()==true){
        current=new convYarPie();
        aux=current.yardasMetros(Double.parseDouble(etxt.getText().toString()));
    }

    txtViewRes.setText(String.valueOf(aux));
}

String contenido;

public void showThirdActivity(View v){

    contenido=txtViewRes.getText().toString();

    Intent i=new Intent(this, ResultadoActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("resultado", contenido);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

ResultActivity.java

```
package displayinsecact.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class ResultadoActivity extends Activity{

TextView tvDatosRecibidos;
String cadena;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resultado);
    tvDatosRecibidos=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDatosRecibidos);

    Bundle recogerDatos=getIntent().getExtras();
    cadena=recogerDatos.getString("resultado");

    tvDatosRecibidos.setText(cadena);
}

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is the second activity" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtViewData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Input Data"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etxt"><requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>

<!--     
chkBoxYarCen, chkBoxCenYar, chkBoxYarMet, chkBoxMetYar, chkBoxYarPie, chkBoxPieYar;  
 -->

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chkBoxYarCen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yards to Centimetres"
    />

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chkBoxCenYar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Centimetres to Yards"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkBoxYarMet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yards to Metres"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkBoxMetYar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Foot to Yards"
    />

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chkBoxYarPie"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yards to Foots"        
    />

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chkBoxPieYar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Foots to Yards"  
    />

<!-- Botones -->
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnOpe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exchange"
    android:onClick="exchange"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtViewRes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Resultado"
    />
```

resultado.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Datos recibidos de la actividad anterior"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDatosRecibidos"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="displayinsecact.project"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:label="Resultado Activity"
        android:name=".Resultadoctivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name=".Resultadoctivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Sorry for the inconvenient.

Comment: where you are calling showThirdActivity method ?

Comment: When do you open the second activity?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in first activity like this

```
 Intent i=new Intent(this, ResultadoActivity.class);
 Bundle b =new Bundle();
 b.putString("resultado", contenido);
 i.putExtras(b);
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: "Extras" is already a `Bundle`. Why would you create a new `Bundle`, put the string in that `Bundle` and then add that `Bundle` to the extras `Bundle`? There's no need for that. It is just confusing and additional unnecessary overhead.